# Permalinks to pages change randomly

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I just created some pages (not posts) on a wordpress site, and a strange thing happens : 
each page have a distinct permalink, that works.
A few time afterwards, I try to access to the page via the permalink, but it leads me to another page that has its own permalink.

For example : http://www.benevolat.org/partenaires/ gives me the page for which permalink is http://www.benevolat.org/assurance-responsabilite-civile-association/.

I tried to modify the permalinks, to change the permalink structure, but the results are the sames. The only structure that works is the default one (?page=XXX).

The only topics I have found on the wordpress forums deal with 404 errors, but it is not my case.

Have you ever faced this ?

Thanks for your help,

Jérémie

Comment: please check your .htaccess, it has the cause.

Comment: I checked its permissions : they are 0666 (the file is not owned by apache, but by me). Before the section `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>` I have some redirections to redirect the URLs of my old site to the new wordpress one, but they do not seem to interfere, since I deactivate them, the effect is the same

Comment: i checked your links, i think this happens for the first time when we open a link. rest of times it works fine. please confirm

Comment: It seems not : If I click on the link "Assurance des associations" (insurances details) on the left, I come to the page which is about subscription, even if I follow it several times.

Comment: No, I think its working fine. Please remove cache from your server and local machine. If you are using any plugin for cache please use that plugin to remove current cache.

Comment: Do you mean Apache's cache ? I use it for images and CSS, but no plugin. I also don't have any cache folder under my site's root dir.

Comment: Don't know why but upgrading from 3.5.1 to 3.6 + disabling Apache's Memory Cache did the trick. I just installed WP Fast Cache in order to raise performances.

Comment: cool, that was what I wanted to point.